# Get Photo URL Given a Photo ID: Facebook Graph API for iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My problem boils down to this: fetch a photo URL given a photo ID. Ultimately, I need to do this for all of the photos a user of my iOS app is tagged in. I am able to get the IDs of the photos with the code:

```
// Create request for user's Facebook data
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters:["fields": "photos"])

    request.startWithCompletionHandler {

        (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil { }
        else if let userData = result as? [String:AnyObject] {
            let userPhotos = userData["photos"]
        }
    }
```

In the returned user data, I have access to the ID of each photo. Now, I defined a function which should (ideally) return the URL of a photo given it's ID. However, I really do not know how to correctly call the Facebook Graph API. This is what I have (note: hardcoded photo ID).

```
 // Create request for user's Facebook data
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/{photo-id}?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", parameters:["fields": "link"])

    request.startWithCompletionHandler {

        (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil { }
        else if let userData = result as? [String:AnyObject] {
            let link = userData["link"]
            print(link)
        }
    }
```

I'm quite confident the the graphPath parameter is wildly wrong. I made some "intelligent" guesses based on this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

Any help you could give me would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The FB documentation suggests just "/{photo-id}". Therefore if your photo had an id of "123456" you would use "/123456". Have you tried that?

Comment: This is correct. Thanks! I had originally tried this, but had a different (unrelated) error.

Comment: This gives a link of the form https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxxxxxxxxxxx&set=p.xxxxxxxxxxxx&type=3, but I would like the link of the form: https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxxxxxxx_ xxxxxxxxxxxx_ xxxxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh= xxxxxxxxxxxx e= xxxxxxxxxxxx. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Also to clarify, the link I want is the link to the publicly accessible photo.

Comment: Looks like the parameter "picture" gives this link for a reduced size version of the photo. This should be sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: @user2585945 could you please share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let requestPhotos = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:id_num, parameters:["fields":"picture, name, album, place"])
```

Where `id_num` is the ID number of the Facebook photo. Very simple.

Comment: Do you mind to share the rest of the code.. because I see that you used above different parameters like link?

Comment: What exactly is your question? To get the link to the photo, I specify "picture" in the parameters array. "Picture" is a link to the 100x100 representation of the photo

Comment: What about getting the URLs for all photos in a single request to show in out table or collectionview imageviews

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is a simple answer, thanks for the answer above @user2585945

import UIKit

```
class FacePhotosViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var imgTest: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            print("We are good!")
        }

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"photos,picture"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print(result)

                let resultdict = result.objectForKey("photos") as! NSDictionary
                let data : NSArray = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray

                for i in 0..<data.count {
                    let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as! NSDictionary
                    let id = valueDict.objectForKey("id") as! String
                    let created_time = valueDict.objectForKey("created_time") as! String
                    print("id: \(id)  created_time: \(created_time)  ")

                }
            }

         })




        let graphRequestPhoto : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "10156292340905363?type=large", parameters: ["fields":"picture, name, album, place"])
        graphRequestPhoto.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            print(result)

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else if let userData = result as? [String:AnyObject] {
                let url = userData["picture"] as? String
                print("link: \(url)")

                let imgURL: NSURL! = NSURL(string: url!)

                //lets' download profile photo
                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()//session
                let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!)//request
                let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in //session calls the request

                    if let noerror = data {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            let image = UIImage(data: noerror)
                            self.imgTest.image = image
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)", terminator: "")
                    }
                }

                dataTask.resume() 
            }


         })








    }
}
```

Comment: You did for a single photo. What about getting the URLs for all photos in a single request to show in out table or collectionview imageviews?